# Manual conversion of a simple C program into assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Take the following C program that has two functions:

```
//  main.c

int times_two(int num) {
    int b = num + num;
    return b;
}

int main(void) {
    int a=2;
    int num = times_two(a) + a;
    return num;
}
```

Is the following a more-or-less accurate way to represent that in x86 assembly? I know this is verbose and I have a bunch of extra push/pop and such on the stacks that I don't need, but does the following more or less faithfully follow the C code?

```
SYS_EXIT = 60

.globl _start
_start:

    call main
    mov %eax, %edi

    mov $SYS_EXIT, %eax
    syscall

main:
    # function() {...
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp

    # int a = 2
    sub $8, %rsp
    movl $2, -4(%rbp)

    # times_two(a)
    movq -4(%rbp), %rdi
    call times_two

    # ... + a
    addl -4(%rbp), %eax

    # ...}  // (return value already in eax)
    add $8, %rsp
    pop %rbp    
    ret


times_two:
    push %rbp
    mov %rsp, %rbp

    # return num + num
    xor %eax, %eax # <-- update: not necessary: next line wipes it out anyways.
    mov %edi, %eax # <-- update: could also do lea (%eax,,2) to multiply by constant
    add %edi, %eax

    pop %rbp
    ret
```

If not, what may I be screwing up or missing/doing wrong?

Comment: `movq -4(%rbp), %rdi` looks bad - you only stored 4 bytes there and you're loading 8.  The top half of `%rdi` will contain garbage, which `times_two` will ignore but it's still bad practice (and an unnecessary unaligned load).  Presumably should be `movl -4(%rbp), %edi`.

Comment: @NateEldredge -- I see: so it should be `movl -4(%rbp), %edi` or store it at `-8` and then change to `movq -8(%rbp), %rdi` ?

Comment: Yes, but if you store it at `-8` you should do that with `movq` as well to zero the high half.  But generally, it's a 32 bit variable so you might as well keep it as such.

Comment: If you want to manually do constant-propagation, you don't need to save `a` in memory across the call.  You know it's still going to be `2` so you can just use another immediate `2`.  So it all comes down to how much you want to emulate a gcc/clang -O0 debug-build (e.g. using `push`/`pop %rbp` in the function that uses no stack space), and how much you want to use common sense and apply the C as-if rule.  Or if you want to write a function that takes a runtime variable arg instead of a compile-time constant, that would justify not using it as an immediate.